# How to conditional SQL select

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

My table consists of `user_id`, `revenue`, `publish_month` columns.
Right now I use `group_by user_id` and `sum(revenue)` to get revenue for all individual users.

Is there a single SQL query I can use to query for user revenue across a time period conditionally? If for a specific user, there is a row for this month, I want to query for this month, last month and the month before. If there is not yet a row for this month, I want to query for last month and the two months before.

Any advice with which approach to take would be helpful. If I should be using cases, if-elses with exists or if this is do-able with a single SQL query?

UPDATE---since I did a bad job of describing the question, I've come to include some example data and expected results

[Where current month is not present for user 33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhm2n.png)

[Where current month is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om5rl.png)

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, but it sounds like you want [lag](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-lag-function/). Can't do much without sample data and desired results.

Comment: It sounds like you want most recent month and the prior two -- but what do you want to do with that time period?  Get the sum of revenue?

Comment: @Hogan that is correct--sum of revenue for most recent month and prior two

Comment: Demonstrating your needs with example data makes it easier to understand, and easier for us to test against. Do *you* test without data? That's why the Minimal Reproducible Example link is *very* important. Often, forcing yourself to make such an example helps you solve it yourself AND is the first step in writing unit tests or regression tests. You do write tests, don't you?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) *(edit your question to include the data as formatted text)*.

Comment: Please tell me that your `publish_month` is actually a `DATE` column, and not a string???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `publish_month` is a DATE datatype, this should get the most recent three months of data per user...

```
SELECT
  user_id, SUM(revenue) as s_revenue
FROM
(
  SELECT
    user_id, revenue, publish_month, 
    MAX(publish_month) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)  AS user_latest_publish_month
  FROM
    yourtableyoudidnotname
)
  summarised
WHERE
  publish_month >= DATEADD(month, -2, user_latest_publish_month)
GROUP BY
  user_id
```

If you want to limit that to the most recent 3 months out of the last 4 calendar months, just add `AND publish_month >= DATEADD(month, -3, DATE_TRUNC(month, GETDATE()))`

- The ambiguity here is why it is important to include a Minimal Reproducible Example
- With input data and require results, we could ***test*** our code against your requirements

> If you're using strings for the `publish_month`, you shouldn't be, and should fix that with utmost urgency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function to "number" the months.  In this way the most recent one will have a value of 1, the prior 2, and the one before 3.  Then you can only select the items with a number of 3 or less.

Here is how:

```
SELECT user_id, revienue, publish_month, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY publish_month DESC) as RN
FROM yourtableyoudidnotname
```

now you just select the items with RN less than 3 and do your sum

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(revenue) as s_revenue
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, revenue, publish_month, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY publish_month DESC) as RN
  FROM yourtableyoudidnotname
) X 
WHERE RN <= 3
GROUP BY user_id
```

You could also do this without a sub query if you use the windowing function for SUM and a range, but I think this is easier to understand.

---

From the comment -- there could be an issue if you have months from more than one year.  To solve this make the biggest number in the order by always the most recent.  so instead of

```
 ORDER BY publish_month DESC
```

you would have

```
 ORDER BY (100*publish_year)+publish_month DESC
```

This means more recent years will always have a higher number so january of 2023 will be 202301 while december of 2022 will be 202212.  Since january is a bigger number it will get a row number of 1 and december will get a row number of 2.

Comment: Thanks, this is mighty helpful. In the case where, for example, there is an entry for this month, December, but not for November, it would be getting the sum for September, October and December? By this approach where we are sorting and getting most recent, I'm assuming we won't be able to get only October and December?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  This uses publish_month and gets the 3 highest values.  If you are going from one year to another you will need to include the year... let me edit the question